# Hide / unhide using jquery resulting in weird effects

Tags: jquery, hide, slidetoggle

I am trying to slide toggle the text box and label within a table. , The slide toggle is working fine but effect is not working smoothly when the check box is clicked the text box and label becomes visible in a weird way , it toggles from right and then leaves the gap between the fields , the gap increases each time the checkbox is clicked. Below is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    var $startdates = $('#startDates');
    var $endDates = $('#endDates');
    $startdates.hide();
    $endDates.hide();

    $('#all').click(function () {
        $startdates.slideToggle('slow');
        $endDates.slideToggle('slow');
        return false;

    });
});
 </script>


<tr id="startDates">
        <td>
        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartDate) %>
        </div>
        </td>
        <td>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StartDate) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartDate) %>
        </div>
        </td>
        </tr>

        <tr id="endDates">
        <td>
        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.EndDate) %>
        </div>
        </td>
        <td>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EndDate) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EndDate) %>
        </div>
        </td>
        </tr><tr></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="All" id="all" /><label>All</label></td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: what does it mean **"weird effects"**.?

Comment: have you checked this out..? if no then pls [Click here](http://chandreshmaheshwari.wordpress.com/2011/05/24/show-hide-div-content-using-jquery/)..Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toggle `tr` and `td` element isn't recommended, expecially if you use effect (**don't use effect on tr** !)

Try this to display your  elements :

Replace `.slideToggle()` by `.show()`, or if it doesn't work, by `.css('display', 'table-row')`

Comment: but i was looking for toggle effect

Comment: My personal advice would be to use div (with [display:table](http://www.digital-web.com/articles/everything_you_know_about_CSS_Is_wrong/) for example), to avoid these 'weired' but recurring problems. But maybe someone will find a solution to correct your problem without changing the code.

Answer (score 1):

Give `.editor-label` and `.editor-field` a height using CSS or javascript.

If no height is set the animate function will not behave correctly because jQuery will have to guess the height is expanding/animating to.